# Bots, SEO and ASP.NET __doPostBack links

Tags: asp.net, bots, dopostback

Does anyone know if, from using linkbuttons and imagebuttons in .net (which render to screen with javascript doPostback methods instead of normal links) you are somehow limiting or adversely affecting your site from an SEO point of view?

Put more clearly - do those types of links stop bots from effectively crawling your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will affect SEO. Bots don't execute javascript, and they don't post forms, so these kinds of links will not be crawled by bots.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying, will have to come up with something else.